# GraalVM polyglot context and Jakarta CDI context: how access beans from scripts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, graalvm

I'm sure I'm missing something, so here's how I understand things as for now:

In order to execute a script we have to provide it with a context which among other things boils down to a set of variable names mapped to their values. We may keep this context if we want the subsequent script snippets to continue mutating the objects we're keeping in the context, or create a new one. This worked for me in older scripting libraries for java.

In my application I'm storing the objects (beans) in a set of `java.util.Map`s that correspond to multiple (potentially hundreds) execution states which my app is working with, calling scripts or changing the beans in java. These contexts are scoped and can be nested hierarchically, like the application scope, process definition scope, process instance scope, process instance thread scope, and I am managing that all myself in a set of Maps.

Because of that, after switching to GraalVM, I have to execute a script the following way:

```
    //TODO: this obviously needs heavy optimization
    Context ctx = Context.newBuilder(lang).allowAllAccess(true).build();
    Value bindings = ctx.getBindings(lang);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : myContext.entrySet()) {
        bindings.putMember(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    Value ret = ctx.eval(lang, script);
```

, where `myContext` is a `Map` that stores all of the nested contexts in one structure, and this thing happens all the time whenever a process dynamically decides to execute a script snippet.

Now I'm wishing to take advantage of Jakarta CDI to manage my beans and scopes and the contexts. Seeing the word "context" I imagined that these two (scripting and application scopes) can be somehow interoperable. Basically, the script has to have access to the beans in all of the nested scopes when it comes to execute it.

For example, I could put an ObjectMapper instance on one level of the scope, and an InputStream on another, and in my script get access to both and make it work.

But I'm failing to grasp the exact way of achieving this. None of them follows the `java.util.Map` API, which is fine, but then, how?

*Add:* would be nice to employ the same mechanism for generating the templated text outputs along the way of execution of my processes. I'm currently using [MVEL](http://mvel.documentnode.com/) which happily accepts a `Map` to populate the placeholders and is also a neat expression language when a full fledged script is an overkill.

By the way, I'm seeing that legacy JSP EL language connection in the Jakarta CDI API through the `CDI.current().getBeanManager().getELResolver()` call, can it be the way to marry it with the GraalVM contexts or am I totally confused?..

Answer (score 1):

Jakarta CDI and Graal Polyglot Context have nothing to do with each other. The word "context" is very overloaded in programming.

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve.

If you want to expose something from Java to Python, you can implement, for example, a [ProxyHashMap](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/proxy/ProxyHashMap.html). If you send such object to Python, it will look like a dictionary, but under the hood it will call the methods from your ProxyHashMap implementation. You can wrap any service locator (be it from Jakarta CDI or any dependency injection framework) and expose it to Python this way, for example.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've noticed they have little to do with each other =) Thanks for pointing to this Proxy. But I think I'm looking for the way to substitute the Polyglot Bindings - the topmost set of variables - with my own structure then. As opposed to putting anything in the existing Bindings that `ctx.getBindings(lang)` is returning